# Compressing multiple cpanel account into separate .tar.gz files

Tags: linux, cron, rsync, tar

My WHM does incremental backup to a remote server. My question is how can compress the directories into separate file and move to a different folder. For example

```
main_dir
 ---account1
 ---account2
 ---account3
```

The second directory should have this

```
 sec_dir
   ---account1.tar.gz
   ---account2.tar.gz
   ---account3.tar.gz
```

I want to create a cronjob to compress all account in the main_dir then move them to the sec_dir

Thx

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this in Python and this is what I found:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467978/python-want-logging-with-log-rotation-and-compression

Comment: Holly guacamole!. This is hard. Isn't there a simpler way just to do the compressing even manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below command for compression

change directory to main_dir

> cd main_dir
>
> tar -cvzf fullpathto/sec_dir/account1.tar.gz account1

or

> for i in `ls fullpath-of-main_dir`; do nice -n 19 /bin/tar -cvzf fullpath-of-sec_dir/$i.tar.gz fullpath-of-main_dir/$i; done

ls to dir is in ' ' commas. I mean use ' in starting and in last `ls fullpath-of-main_dir`

Comment: Robbin, 
This is only for one folder. I want to compress all of them to separate files with one command. Thank you

Comment: for i in ls ~/test/b1; do nice -n 19 tar -cvzf ~/test/b2/$i.tar.gz ~/test/b1/$i; done

tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/hab/test/b1/ls: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/hab/test/b1//home/hab/test/b1: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar (child): /home/hab/test/b2//home/hab/test/b1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Hey, it seems you have not used '' as 'ls fullpath-of-main_dir' or might b there is typo from me, try it as below:                         for i in `ls /var/www/html/test/`; do /bin/tar -cvzf /var/www/html/backup/$i.tar.gz /var/www/html/test/$i/; done

Comment: Please use 'ls fullpath-of-main_dir' donot use without single commas, '_' are must.  I have tested it works for me.