# python logging config file, one per day, not multiple

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to create a log config file that will create one complete log per day, but at the moment it creates multiple files;

```
ie. 
readings.log.2013-06-17_01
readings.log.2013-06-17_02
readings.log.2013-06-17_03
readings.log.2013-06-17_04
readings.log.2013-06-17_05
readings.log.2013-06-17_06
readings.log.2013-06-18_01
readings.log.2013-06-18_02
readings.log.2013-06-18_03
readings.log.2013-06-18_04
readings.log.2013-06-18_05
readings.log.2013-06-18_06
...etc
```

I'm sure I have missed something, but what do I need to change in my logging config file to make it create just one complete logfile PER day, regardless of size!>?

Using Python 2.7 atm and the script runs 24/7

Thx
Matt.

My Logging config file; (logging_v3.cfg)

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
handlers=screen,file
level=NOTSET

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex,logtemps

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s

[formatter_complex]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s : %(lineno)d - %(message)s

[formatter_logtemps]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s

[handlers]
keys=file,screen

[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
backupCount=0
formatter=logtemps
level=INFO
args=('logs/readings.log',)

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=simple
level=DEBUG
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

And the code I have in my program to make the above work; (obviously there is a lot more but this is the main part for the logging)

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('config/logging_v3.cfg') #logfile config

logging.debug("DEBUG MODE")
logging.debug("INFO MODE")
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I would try changing `args=('logs/readings.log',)` to `args=('logs/readings.log','midnight',)` - that looks like it'll pass the interval parameter as expected; I'm not sure what keys you can use in the logging config files, and it doesn't seem to be clearly documented as far as I can tell?

Comment: I think it's basically answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467978/python-want-logging-with-log-rotation-and-compression

Comment: @9000, saw that one, but wasn't sure how to add it into a config file, like my setup.

Comment: @ernie, thx, works a lot better now.

Another quick question, setting the backupcount=0, does that mean that it will not delete any of the logs? and likewise if I set it to 30, it will keep 30days of logs?

Comment: My reading of [the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) suggests that's correct, i.e. "If backupCount is nonzero, at most backupCount files will be kept, and if more would be created when rollover occurs, the oldest one is deleted. The deletion logic uses the interval to determine which files to delete, so changing the interval may leave old files lying around."  You may need to pass that in the args as well, e.g. `args=('logs/readings.log', 'midnight', 'backupCount=0')` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codifying the comments into an answer:

The documentation for the [logging Configuration file format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format) seems a little unclear as to what are valid options for keys and values in each section.

For the handlers, it appears to pass arguments to the constructors, we need to use the `args` key, and specify the values there, rather than using key-value pairs in the config section, e.g. instead of:

```
[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
interval=midnight
args=('logs/readings.log',)
```

We should use:

```
[handler_file]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
args=('logs/readings.log', 'midnight',)
```