# Logging to a file from a python worker process in a uWsgi environment

Tags: python, logging, concurrency, uwsgi

I have a Flask app deployed using Docker compose, accompanied by a small DB and a uWsgi frontend. There are certain outputs from the flask app that I want written to a specific log file. The idea is that on midnight, I want the log file rotated to the next day while a backup of the previous X amount of days is kept. I have configured the log file when the app first launches like so:

```
handler = TimedCompressedRotatingFileHandler('/home/root/custom_logs/no_RS_queries_planner_api.log',
                                             when="midnight", encoding='utf8', backupCount=14)

logger = logging.getLogger('query_logger')
logger.addHandler(handler)
handler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d"

# the all-important app variable:
application = Flask(__name__)

#sample log
logger.warning(value1,value2,value3)
```

This works when I test the Flask app locally on my machine as running it only uses one process. But if I try to deploy it with uWsgi with multiple workers defined.....:

```
; app.ini

[uwsgi]
protocol = uwsgi

chdir=/app/app/

; This is the name of our Python file
; minus the file extension
module = main

; This is the name of the variable
; in our script that will be called
callable = application

master = true;

; Set uWSGI to start up x workers
processes = 9

; We use the port 5000 which we will
; then expose on our Dockerfile
socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
vacuum = trued

die-on-term = true
```

All worker processes do a rollover on the same file at midnight. Essentially overwriting it several times and causing me to lose the log file. This seems to still be a current issue in these kinds of deployments and is quite annoying to try and solve. Is there any simple method to handle this sort of thing without having to massively re-structure my app?

For reference, `TimedCompressedRotatingFileHandler` is a modification of an existing log rotation class taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9587563/2485799). I've tried a few cheeky approaches such as trying to get the uWsgi worker ID and append that to the log file as an additional suffix but that does not seem to work and just outputs `0`. I could try logging to the DB and outputting it on a schedule at midnight but would prefer trying a logging approach first.

Can anyone help me find a quick solution to my woes?

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is [described in the cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes), albeit for a slightly different case - multiple processes using `multiprocessing`:

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from multiple threads in a single process is supported, logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple processes in Python.

Of course, in your case the problem is not just in writing to the log file from multiple processes, but also rollover of the same file from multiple processes.

One solution for your scenario is:

1. All your uWSGI workers should use a logging configuration which doesn't use your file handler directly, but uses a `SocketHandler` to send logged events across a socket (either TCP/IP sockets or Unix domain sockets, if available).
2. You should have a separate process, which listens on this socket, and processes the logging events received from it by logging them to the file handler.

This approach keeps the writing to the file and the rolling over in a single process, so the problem you describe shouldn't occur. The cookbook also contains [an example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) of using a `SocketHandler` to send logging events across a network. You should be able to adapt the code there to a listener process without too much trouble.