# Prevent third party modules to write same log

Tags: python, windows

I've got two problems:

---

**1:**

I initialize my log by:

```
Path(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent) + "\\log").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent) + "\\log\\" + time.strftime(
        "%d.%m.%Y_%H%M%S") + ".log",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="[%(asctime)s ThreadID:%(thread)d %(levelname)s:%(name)s]: %(message)s",
    datefmt="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
)
logging.info("Started")
```

And calling it in multiple instances by:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Now the Problem here is that we use an api which calles the same funciton as above. So my log file is full of the stuff they write into theirs. It's probably because I use the .basicConfig in the beginning of my program but I need it to be there.

---

**2:**

I want the log file to split and compress after a certain interval. I know there is a way via the [TimedRotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler). There is already a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467978/python-want-logging-with-log-rotation-and-compression) on that. I was trying to use the second solution.
But how do I use that like I did before. Because now I run into the problem that I can't compress the file and write in it at the same time which makes sens but I don't know a way arround it.

---

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: The newer (python 3) answers of the linked question look good, too. Also here is an example from the logging cookbook: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-rotator-and-namer-to-customize-log-rotation-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the first part of my question I found a solution it works by not using the `logging.basicConfig`. Now I am using an seperate initializer for each logger instance I call. It might not be the fastest but it works and keeps out unwanted logs of other modules.

```
import logging

handler = logging.FileHandler(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent) + 
          "\\log\\" + time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y_%H%M") + ".log")

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="[%(asctime)s ThreadID:%(thread)d %(levelname)s:% 
            (name)s]: %(message)s",datefmt="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

handler.setFormatter(formatter)


def init(basicLogger):
     Path(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent) + 
     "\\log").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) # Checking if path exists if not 
                                                   creates it

     basicLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
     basicLogger.addHandler(handler)

     return basicLogger
```

---

You call it in the function you want to log in via:

```
import logging
import # path to the file above

log = init(logging.getLogger(__name__))

log.info("Hello World) # Then you can use the logger like normal
```